# FullpageJS - Vertical Navigation anchors

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, fullpage.js, anchor-scroll

First post here, I'll try to make myself super clear. 
I'm using the FullpageJS Library (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) on rails app and I can't figure how to navigate between sections (of the same page). I've looked up for some tutorials and topics on the internet but when I tried those solutions, same problem, my website literally freeze.

I am using vanilla JS to get the library working and until now everything worked fine.

I should precise that when i'm typing the url like www.mysite.com/#contact the animation is working fine. The problem occurs when i'm clicking on a link.

Thanks a lot :)

Here is my code :

```js
 new fullpage("#fullpage", {
    //options here
    licenseKey: ...,
    autoScrolling: true,
    navigation: true,
    keyboardScrolling: true,
   animateAnchor: true,
    anchors: ['home', 'about', 'project', 'cv', 'contact']
    )};
```

```html
<div class="fullpage" id="fullpage">  
       <section class="section s1" data-anchor="home">
            <h1>blabla</h1>
            <a href="#about" class="menu-item"></a>
            <a href="#project" class="menu-item"></a>
            <a href="#cv" class="menu-item"></a>
            <a href="#contact" class="menu-item"></a>
        </section>
        <section class="section s2" data-anchor="about">
            <h1>À propos</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="section s3" data-anchor="projet">
         
            <h1>Projet</h1>
            
        </section>
        <section class="section s4" data-anchor="cv">
           
            <h1>CV</h1>
           
        </section>
        <section class="section s5" data-anchor="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </section>
      </div>
```

### strong text

Comment: What's the issue? Any reproduction we can see?

Comment: Hey Alvaro, 

Problem solved, I was stupidly calling the script tag in the wrong place ...

Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you did! :)